# Dynamically change function of ng-click based on route

Tags: angularjs

I have an app with many views. On most views I have a toggle-able drawer on the left hand side for navigation. However, on a few views I want the menu to be a back button instead.

I am trying to use ng-click and databinding.

```
md-button ng-click="{{$scope.current.navBarFunction}}"
```

to dynamically inject the name, from an attribute navBarFunction in my routes, of the function for ng-click However this doesn't work and I'm unsure how to continue.

```
.when('/articles/:articleId', {
    title: 'articles.title',
    icon: 'arrow_back',
    navBarFunction: 'backButton()',
    templateUrl: 'views/articles/:articleid.html',
    controller: 'ArticlesArticleidCtrl',
    resolve: {
      loggedin: checkLoggedin
    }
  })
```

Furthermore, is there anyway to make an if statement in app.js using the current route? That would simplify things.

EDIT 1:

here's more code in our controller:

```
function navBack(pageID) {
  $location.path( '/' + pageID );
}

function buildToggler(navID) {
  var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
        $mdSidenav(navID)
          .toggle()
          .then(function () {
            $log.debug('toggle ' + navID + ' is done');
          });
      },300);
  return debounceFn;
}

$scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');
$scope.navBackUsers = navBack('users');
$scope.navBackArticles = navBack('articles');
$scope.navBackClassrooms = navBack('classrooms');
```

Comment: Your ng-click function looks odd to me

Comment: @ABOS that's what I'm trying to fix. I want to dynamically change what the value of ng-click is, I tried to do it with databinding but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code it should likely be:

```
ng-click="current.navBarFunction()"
```

Not sure why you have `()` in string value in router or how you are setting this up in directive or controller. Seeing more code would help

Comment: Basically I have a button a toolbar. On most pages I want ng-click to lead to a function called toggleLeft() that opens a small drawer on the left, however on some pages I want ng-click to run a function called backButton() which will return the viewer to the last page. I am currently dynamically creating the icon by using $route.current.icon, a value I stored in my .when statement for each route. I want to do this for methods as well, or some other, cleaner, method for dynamically changing the ng-click.

Comment: seems like would be simpler to not have to add this to every route, and only add a property to the few routes that need different functionality ...as a boolean. Then in controller or directive `if($route.current.useBackButton){...}`

Comment: When I try to create an if statement in the main controller using $route.current.useBackButton, or some other property, it always errors out with 'cannot read property useBackButton" of undefined.